# List of Hyper-V Servers Remotely into CSV Format?

Tags: powershell, virtual-machine, hyper-v

Im thinking this would be easy, but want to make sure it's possible.

Is there an easy way to grab a list of all Hyper-V Servers/VM's on a machine and maybe export it to a CSV File? (excel spreadsheet).

Get-VM returns quite a bit of information, but is there any way to split that? Maybe store them into an array?

This is my first time with powershell so Im mainly wanting to make sure this is a easily doable task.

Problem is.....the machine is a Windows 2008 Server R2 that doesn't support Hyper-V Modules I believe (I think only Win 8 does).....so I've been remoting into it....so can I use Powershell to Remote into it and Run this script?

I tried doing a Get-VM from command line using Invoke-Command, but it complains about File-Path....but I was just trying to do a Get-VM from command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds to me like you need to take some smaller steps first.  In this case, I would avoid PowerShell remoting.  If you have the modules installed and and loaded in your PowerShell session you should be able to point to a remote host to run Get-VM without having to do anything crazy.

As for filtering output for a CSV, You should use Select (to select certain properties of the object and ignore others) and Where-Object (to filter what objects are displayed, based on properties of the object.

```
Get-VM -ComputerName HyperVHost.constoso.local | Where-Object {$_.OS -match "2008"} | Select Name, Host | ExportTo-CSV C:\csv.csv
```

The above example was fictional, but it's the syntax I would use to filter input before putting it into a CSV.  Again, it sounds like you're going to need a more basic understanding of how to work with the pipeline, understand what options you have to work with objects, etc.

Comment: Ya Im having some issues with just running Get-VM, since it's saying the "Hyper-V Role is not installed on that machine" but I can't since it's 2008 R2 which does not support Import-Module Hyper-V. But When trying to enter a PSSSession....Putting the Computer Name/IP doesn't work. But I think this has to do with firewall and such.....arggg was hoping to avoid all that.